# Mount Network Drive Locally in MFC(VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to Mount Network Drive Locally in MFC(VC++) ?
Currently I am using WNetAddConnection2 to mount drive but it mount drive on network, I want to mount it has locally.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to use a drive letter to attach a network share? I would call the system command net, like so:

net use X: \server\share /PERSISTENT:NO

where X is the drive letter you want to use. The PERSISTENT flag prevents it from remounting on boot. When you're finished, call net again with:

net use X: /DELETE

and it will umount the share.

Comment: @Can i use this command directly in our MFC(VC++ ) project ? Are there any drawbacks for it ?

Comment: Yes - use ShellExecute (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx for more information). I'm not aware of any drawbacks, but the drive will appear in My Computer while it's mapped - that may or may not be a problem for your application.